# Cannot see Oracle database using OLE DB

Tags: excel, database, oracle, oledb, odac

I am trying to connect to a Oracle 12c database from Excel 2016 using 64-bit ODAC 12,2c Release 1 for windows x64. I go to get data and choose Oracle Provider for OLE DB, in Data Link Properties page I fill in details, with the user database specified, and test the connection, which is a success. Instead of showing the user database the system database is shown (Schema tables like OPS$Username, SYS…). Any idea why I cannot see the user database using OLE DB but I can using ODBC with MS Query?

Comment: Maybe you just have to scroll down in the list.

Comment: There is no list to scroll down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a system ODBC to Oracle through control panel as admin. In Power Query, go to new data source, other sources, odbc. The new system ODBC will be there